# can we call a ftl macro from javascript function

Tags: freemarker

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Java, Spring Boot, FreeMarker</title>
    <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
        <@test/>
}
</script>
<body>
    <h2>Java, Spring Boot, FreeMarker</h2>
     <form action="/search" method="post">
   Search : <input type="text" name="firstName" onkeyup="myFunction()" id = "fname"> 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
        <div style="background-color:lightblue">
          <#macro test>
            <#list empList as emp>
            <div id="emp-data">
            <ul>
                <li>${emp}</li>
            </ul>
            </#list>
            </div>
        </#macro>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    </div>

</body>
```

When I run this code I am getting some errors on the browser console:

> (index):60 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup ((index):60) onkeyup @ (index):60 – PCS 1 hour ago

Is it possible in FreeMarker to do something like that?

Comment: put the error here

Comment: (index):60 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup ((index):60)
onkeyup @ (index):60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense you can... but it doesn't do what you apparently believe it does. First all FreeMarker instructions, like `<@test/>`, are resolved on the server, then later the resulting output runs in the browser. So as far as the browser sees, `function myFunction() { ... }`  contains HTML `div`-s directly in inside the `{ ... }`, which is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: My aim is to implement a search filter I can either make a service call onkeyup and filter the records at server side but I think that is not a appropriate way so is there any way to implement the search filter at client side ?

Comment: Solved the problem using simple  javascript function thanks for the hint I was trying to call a ftl macro for filterning the data but I didn't think data is already loaded in the form so I can use javascript for filtering the data